How do you join the rig to the armature so i can pose them together?
How do you join the rig to the armature so I can pose them together? If I select both of them and right click then join, an error comes up. And when I select both of them them use boolean tool, another error comes up. how can I make them join so when I move a rig for a pose, the armature moves with it?




enter image description here


That's a very basic question which is better explained elsewhere. Suggest you watch one of the many YT videos on armatures and rigging.

Hello maybe explain more in detail your case, what is your object and armature, also show a screenshot, etc
